# How to show that for $x,y$ rational, $x < \frac{1+y\sqrt{2}}{1+x\sqrt{2}}<y$?

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to answer the following exercise:

> [image]

I showed that $z$ is irrational. Now I'm stuck trying to show that $x<z<y$. How can I do that? I tried a lot of stuff but nothing works.

Comment: I don't think it's true. When $x = y$ that fraction is exactly $1$, so if $y = x + \epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$, the fraction is still close to $1$. Hence if $x = 2$ for example, the fraction wouldn't be between $x$ and $y$ for small enough $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Zarrax $x,y$ are different. See the image.

Comment: I know, I'm saying make $y = x + \epsilon$ for sufficiently small positive $\epsilon$. For example, the inequality fails for $x = 2$ and $y = 2.1$.

Comment: I think it supposed to be something like $\frac{x+y\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}$ (i. e. the number which divides the segment $[x,y]$ in ratio $\sqrt{2}:1$).

Answer (score 3):

It is not true: if $x=0$ and $y=1$, then $z= \frac{1+y\sqrt{2}}{1+ x\sqrt{2}}=1+\sqrt{2} > y.$